# Inserting values into a table which is composite primary key with 3 columns, those colums are foreign keys

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

My table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE tblUserFollower
 (
     UserID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblUsers(UserID),
     FollowerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblUsers(UserID),
     SubCourseID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblSubCourse(SubCourseID),
     StatusID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblStatus(StatusID),
     IsActive BIT NOT NULL,
     CreatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     CreatedBy NVARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'ADMIN',
     UpdatedDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'ADMIN',

     PRIMARY KEY(UserID, FollowerID, SubCourseID)
)
```

I want to write a stored procedure to insert values into this table.

Comment: Why do you need stored procedure?  Just insert.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? Not all databases deal with all the details the same way - please add a relevant tag like `sql-server`, `mysql`, `oracle`, `postgresql`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using